# `post_type` => `any` not giving me my custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, frontpage, theme-roots

I'm using Roots Bedrock + Sage 9 Beta 3. I've created a custom post of type `lp` that I want to set as my homepage. Here is the code I'm using:

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_lp() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Landing Pages.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name"          => __( 'Landing Pages', 'sage' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'Landing Page', 'sage' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label"               => __( 'Landing Pages', 'sage' ),
        "labels"              => $labels,
        "description"         => "Pages without menus and/or totally custom layouts.",
        "public"              => true,
        "publicly_queryable"  => true,
        "show_ui"             => true,
        "show_in_rest"        => false,
        "rest_base"           => "",
        "has_archive"         => false,
        "show_in_menu"        => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => true,
        "capability_type"     => "post",
        "map_meta_cap"        => true,
        "hierarchical"        => false,
        "rewrite"             => [ "slug" => "lp", "with_front" => true ],
        "query_var"           => true,
        "menu_icon"           => "dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus",
        "supports"            => [ "title", "thumbnail", "excerpt" ],
    );

    register_post_type( "lp", $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_lp' );
```

I've installed [mpress-custom-front-page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mpress-custom-front-page/) but it doesn't seem to see my landing page.

#### So, with some digging, I noticed that it uses `get_posts()` to get posts with `post_type = 'any'`.

The query it sends is so:

```
$queried_post = get_posts([
  'posts_per_page' => - 1,
  'orderby'        => 'title',
  'order'          => 'ASC',
  'post_type'      => 'any',
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
]);
```

#### This query returns all of the posts *except* my custom post types:

[image]

#### If I redo this exact query, but set `post_type` to `'lp'` then I get my post, no problem:

[image]

## Why would `any` not find my custom post type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when registering your post type you have `'exclude_from_search' => true`

`get_posts()` is just passing that to `WP_Query`. In the [parameter definitions for `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters) it states:

> 'any' - retrieves any type except revisions and types with **'exclude_from_search' set to true**.